# WCF image upload service

Tags: wcf

Could any one possibly direct me to a example of how to do a WCF image upload service.
I have tried to change my config increasing the size but its still not helping.  If i had a full service example it would really help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx) on MSDN which shows how to upload/download streams in a WCF service.